# Applying standardization using ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, keras, preprocessing, normalization

I have a multiclass image dataset ( 8 classes) that is divided as follows, the main folder is called training and I have 8 subfolders with each subfolder for one class. I know how to perform data standardization using ImageDataGenerator :

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
samplewise_center=True,
rescale=1. / 255,
shear_range=30,
zoom_range=30,
rotation_range=20,
width_shift_range=0.2,
height_shift_range=0.2)
```

then :

```
train_datagen.fit(x_train)
```

My problem is with `x_train`, I don't know how I could pass my dataset as `x_train` ? They are contained in a directory as described above and they are 8 classes ( and hence 8 folders )?

Comment: If your data it not loaded into memory yet but only stored in a directory you will have to use the [`flow_from_directory`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory) method instead of the `fit` method.

Comment: @Oxbowerce , but how I can calculate the stats then ? According to my understanding, the train_datage.fit() is the method that calculates the stats.  required for standardization.

Comment: You don't need to since this is only needed if you are standardizing based on the feature level, but you are not using the `featurewise_center` or `featurewise_std_normalization` arguments (see also [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#fit). The 'standardizations' you are applying can simply be done with data present in a specific sample or batch without needing any statistics from the whole dataset. The examples sections of the docs shows how to you can use the `flow_from_directory` method when just rescaling.

Comment: @Oxbowerce Thanks a lot for your help! I have another question, what if I need to do the standardization feature-wise? How could I do it in my case with .fit()? Note I have enough memory to load all the data at once .

Comment: If you have the memory to load all the data in memory, you have to load all the data by yourself first into a single array/tensor before calling `fit` on that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data it not loaded into memory yet but only stored in a directory you will have to use the [`flow_from_directory`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory) method instead of the `fit` method. The `fit` method is only needed if you are standardizing based on the feature level (or when you already have all data loaded into memory), but you are not using the `featurewise_center` or `featurewise_std_normalization` arguments (see also [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#fit)). The 'standardizations' you are applying can simply be done with data present in a specific sample or batch without needing any statistics from the whole dataset. The examples sections of the docs shows how to you can use the `flow_from_directory` method when just rescaling.